# Как сменить версию Java в webShtrom

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk11

У меня установлена java версии 1.8, но при выполнении команды java --version, получаю ответ что версия: openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16, хотя в папке с jdk/jre у меня только 1.8. (надо для webShtrom, не путайте с idea)

Comment: https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml в разделе соответствующей ОС

Comment: переменную path создал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во многих продуктах JetBrains последних версий поставляется так называемый JBR. Это сборка OpenJDK (как я думаю) от JetBrains. По умолчанию программа будет использовать её для запуска и работы. Возможно, JBR не будет и тогда используется то, что записано в переменной среды `JAVA_HOME`.

Чтобы в целом, как бы по умолчанию, выбрать определённый JDK следует править переменную среды `JAVA_HOME`.

При выполнении команды `java --version` будет использоваться тот JDK, что в переменной среды `JAVA_HOME`.

Для выбора JDK для запуска продуктов JetBrains следует открыть любой проект, в дважды щёлкнуть по Shift вводить "*Switch Boot JDK*" и щёлкнуть по предложенному пункту меню. Дальше поймёте.

JetBrains рекомендует использовать в качестве JDK для запуска JBR, иначе Oracle JDK 8 или 11 для Windows или OpenJDK 8 или 11 для систем Linux.